# How do I return a correctly rounded answer in Python?

Tags: python, rounding

I am writing a script that asks the user for the numbers of coins of different denominations that they have, then displays the total sum in dollars and cents.

When it displays dollars, however, it rounds the answer.

For example, if the total is 82 cents, it states that I have 1 dollar while I need it to say 0 dollars.

I can't make use of the **`round`** function appropriately here.

Is it even a smart thing to use or should I stick with the **`format`** function?

```
def main():
    pennies  = get_input( "Enter pennies  : " )
    nickels  = get_input( "Enter nickels  : " )
    dimes    = get_input( "Enter dimes    : " )
    quarters = get_input( "Enter quarters : " )

    print( "You Entered : " )
    print( "\tPennies   : " , pennies )
    print( "\tNickels   : " , nickels )
    print( "\tDimes     : " , dimes )
    print( "\tQuarters  : " , quarters )

    total_value     = get_total(           pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters )
    dollars         = get_dollars(         pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters )
    left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents( pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters )

    print( "Total = $",format( total_value, ".2f" ), sep = "" )
    print( "You Have", format( dollars, ".0f" ), "dollars and", left_over_cents, "cent(s)" )

def get_input( message ):
    notify = int( input( "I don't know" ) )
    while notify >= 0:
        return notify

def get_total( pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters ):
    pennies         = .01 * pennies;
    nickels         = .05 * nickels;
    dimes           = .10 * dimes;
    quarters        = .25 * quarters;
    total_value     = pennies + nickels + dimes + quarters
    return total_value

def get_dollars( pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters ):
    pennies         = .01 * pennies;
    nickels         = .05 * nickels;
    dimes           = .10 * dimes;
    quarters        = .25 * quarters;
    total_value     = pennies + nickels + dimes + quarters
    dollars         = total_value
    return dollars

def get_left_over_cents( pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters ):
    pennies         = .01 * pennies;
    nickels         = .05 * nickels;
    dimes           = .10 * dimes;
    quarters        = .25 * quarters;
    total_value     = pennies + nickels + dimes + quarters
    left_over_cents = total_value
    return left_over_cents

main()
```

Comment: If you're counting money, *never* use floating point at all. Stick to integers.

Comment: Actually, decimal would probably be the best type.

Comment: Demonstrated how to use decimal for this to round down to dollars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically best is to use `decimal.Decimal` for monetary values:

```
import decimal
penny_value = decimal.Decimal('.01')
nickle_value = decimal.Decimal('.05')
dime_value = decimal.Decimal('.10')
quarter_value = decimal.Decimal('.25')
```

If you're keeping count of coins, you should multiply the above constants by your number of coins, and you won't have rounding errors.

```
pennies = 2
nickles = 1
dimes = 0
quarters = 3

total_value = (pennies * penny_value + nickles * nickle_value + 
               dimes * dime_value + quarters * quarter_value)
dollars = total_value.quantize(1, rounding=decimal.ROUND_DOWN)
```

and `dollars` is now `Decimal('0')` which is equal to zero.

```
>>> print total_value
0.82
>>> print dollars
0
```

If you want to stick to ints and floats to round down, convert to int, which will round towards zero:

```
total_value = .82

dollar_value = int(total_value)
```

`dollar_value` is now `0`

To use this approach, do this:

```
def get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    pennies = .01 * pennies;
    nickels = .05 * nickels;
    dimes = .10 * dimes;
    quarters = .25 * quarters;
    total_value= pennies + nickels + dimes + quarters
    dollars = int(total_value)
    return dollars
```

Comment: Using the int(total_value) gave me the answer I required.  I had to do:

print("You Have", dollars, "dollars and", format(left_over_cents,".2f"), "cent(s)")

and this rounded my cents to the two decimal places required as well.